# the UK Family permit condition (EEA citizen traveling with non-EEA spouse)

Tags: uk-visa, eu-spouses

How to prove my EEA spouse is, in fact, traveling with me to the UK?

I submitted an application to the visa4uk website to get a Family Permit for myself.

How do I prove that the EEA citizen is traveling with me? Do I provide flight tickets or do I include a letter from my wife stating we're traveling together?

How do I write such a letter? I read over the internet to ask for the permit (Kindly and respectfully ask for the Family Permit to be issued, as indicated on DIRECTIVE 2004/38C)

please advise

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How to prove my EEA spouse is, in fact, traveling with me to the UK?

It is not necessary to do so in your application.  The immigration officer may ask about this when you enter, although it is unlikely because you will be with her then.

> How do I prove that the EEA citizen is traveling with me? Do I provide flight tickets or do I include a letter from my wife stating we're traveling together?

You should not include flight tickets because you should not book your flight until after the family permit is granted.  If you book the tickets before, you risk losing the fare if the permit is denied.  You do not need to include a letter from your wife, either.  Just mention your travel plans in response to the questions in the application.

Comment: there are cases where people submitted support letters
http://www.expatforum.com/expats/britain-expat-forum-expats-living-uk/166184-eea-family-permit-support-letter-eea-national.html#/topics/166184?page=5

Comment: @Palio yes.  Submitting a support letter will not cause the application to be refused.  However, it is not necessary to include a support letter.